# In Matthew 14 Jesus walks on the water. What are the similarities between this account and the ancient Egyptian writings about Horus?

Tags: jesus, matthew, history, egypt

In Matthew 14 Jesus walks on the water. What are the similarities and differences between this account and the ancient Egyptian writings about Horus from Pyramid texts in 25th Century BC?

For example, the [Zeitgeist movie](http://conspiracies.skepticproject.com/articles/zeitgeist/part-one/#horus) claims:

> Broadly speaking, the story of Horus is as follows: Horus was born on December 25th of the virgin Isis-Meri. His birth was accompanied by a star in the east, which in turn, three kings followed to locate and adorn the new-born savior. At the age of 12, he was a prodigal child teacher, and at the age of 30 he was baptized by a figure known as Anup and thus began his ministry. Horus had 12 disciples he traveled about with, performing miracles such as healing the sick and **walking on water**. Horus was known by many gestural names such as The Truth, The Light, God's Anointed Son, The Good Shepherd, The Lamb of God, and many others. After being betrayed by Typhon, Horus was crucified, buried for 3 days, and thus, resurrected.

Comment: I think that separation by ~2500 years would be enough to distance the stories, though with the emergence of the library in Alexandria perhaps there were some new stories circulating.

I guess that beyond that initial textual parallels, I'd also like to hear about any emerging corroborating stories (perhaps in Greco-Roman mythology) that were contemporary with the writing of the gospels.

Comment: I'm voting to close because the question doesn't really seem to be so much about a Biblical text as about some claims about Jesus.  If there's a better primary source on the Horus myth, I'd like to see it.  Maybe if the two accounts are laid side-by-side, we could do some real examination of the text.

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1678

Comment: Context - I don't recognise the similarities - but am speaking with people that do. I'm trying to open my mind to the possibilities there might be similarities. Perhaps someone could provide links to a translation of the the Horus text...

Comment: It seems [Egyptologists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jesus_Christ_in_comparative_mythology#Ancient_Egypt) reject most of the similarities between Horus and Jesus that were suggested by [Gerald Massey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerald_Massey), who seems to have originated the idea.  I can't source the walking on water claim for Horus at all.  It's almost certainly a fabrication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Abstract

None.  Or at least nothing substantial.

---

The claim that some story about Jesus is really a retelling of some other story about some mythical figure assumes that 1<sup>st</sup> century Christians would have:

1. Known the former myth and
2. Hoped other people wouldn't notice the similarities.

Because the early Christians seemed to have *believed* these stories even at the cost of their own lives.  Paul is explicit:

> Why are we in danger every hour? I protest, brothers, by my pride in you, which I have in Christ Jesus our Lord, I die every day! What do I gain if, humanly speaking, I fought with beasts at Ephesus? If the dead are not raised, “Let us eat and drink, for tomorrow we die.”—1<sup>st</sup> Corinthians 15:30-32 ([ESV](http://www.esvbible.org/search/1%20Corinthians+15/))

---

But to the specific claim that Jesus walking on water is a retelling of some story about Horus, that seems to be a [myth](http://conspiracies.skepticproject.com/articles/zeitgeist/part-one/#horus) itself:

> I, as well as several others, as well as several Egyptologists you can find on the Internet, know of no reference anywhere to a "star in the east" or "three kings" and "new-born savior"; it is simply made up. I cannot find any source or information proving he was a "teacher when he was 12 years old", that he was "baptized at age 30", that he "walked on water" (but on the Internet, I did find several places that suggest he was "thrown in the water", but I have no direct source at this time for that). More so, I cannot find any evidence he was referred to as "The Truth", "The Light", Lamb of God", "the Good Shepherd", etc.—Edward L Winston

The above quote is by a skeptic who debunked the ridiculous Zeitgeist Movie.  Frankly, it seems that myths about Horus were created (in the last few years) based on the life of Jesus and not the other way around.

Comment: I voted to close, since the question seemed off-topic and belongs on [Skeptics.SE](http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1678).  But I feel like there is a straightforward answer that belongs here.  Perhaps the question can be improved...

Comment: I'm open to any improvements to the question. I ask in an apologetics context speaking to skeptics.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I'm not breaking the rules posting a link here, but I've followed the theme of walking on water back to the Garden of Eden - if you're interested. It all starts with the spring under the Garden, flowing into the world as rivers of life. We also see it in the crossing of Jordan "dryshod," the necessity of the priests having clean feet, and Jesus washing His disciples' feet. To be "above the Laver" is to be an advisor in God's courtroom, walking on the crystal sea as an elder.

http://www.bullartistry.com.au/wp/2010/05/01/walking-on-water/

Before anyone asks how I can make such connections, it is through the observation of a repeated architecture (Eden-Tabernacle-Temple-Word) and the position of the water at step 6 of a repeated heptamerous pattern. It's cross-eyed exegesis:
http://www.bullartistry.com.au/wp/2010/10/13/cross-eyed-exegesis/

Comment: Interesting - perhaps you should post your hypothesis as a question on this forum and ask people's view on whether it stacks up.

Answer (score 0):

Let me assume you are correct and there are Egyptian texts that prove these christian symbolisms are plagiarism. Subsequently as a religious teacher, I will tell you that, Egyptian, Greek, summarian, and most of other old religious of the world are in fact something like shadows of the Hebrew and Christian chronicles. Something like counterfeit forerunners. They may be correct and older, but in fact, they seem to have had the knowledge of the great coming of Christ, and some of their own symbolisms are tailored to fit the perspectives and representations of the greater light/story in their own gods— which is of the prophesies of Jesus. The Asian ying yeng story is an incomplete version of the Adam and Eve allegory. The Greek Olympians vs titans blab is something tailored from the Hebrew descriptions of the war in Heavens against Lucifer. These gods and symbolisms are replicas of a truer allegory. The greek and egyptian texts depict demons that assume the roles of gods, who do not even have control over their own souls. The Hebrew God created Hell or whatever it is called in their religions to imprison the devil and his fallen angels— even the Greek and Egyptian gods have no answer to the creation of the underworld-like replicas and are not immune to it. And have it in mind that the bible never even gives account of how many wise men there were, and if the star in the east is even the sirus star it is ascribed to. And it is not entirely impossible that the people and writers of that period wouldn't have tried to align the stories to stories of the older religions, in a bid to overshadow their symbolisms.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I think the writers of the Holy Bible, Kings James Version, copied and plagiarized the life identity of Horus and bestowed it upon Jesus.  It is strange how this fictional character named Jesus didn't not leave any carbon footsteps or writings of his own. Why is it that other people have to write about this historical person they called Jesus.  The question is, why didn't Jesus do any of his own writings if he was such a historical figure and the Son of God?  Why is it that the Romans, who are so meticulous in their writings  have no mention about this man they called Jesus. A man who claim he was the son of God that could raise the dead, walk on water and make a blind man see?

The Christians have an agenda and that is to keep the Christian faith going at all cost. The Christian have to much to lose for their followers to find out that they have given and living a possible lie for the past 2000 years. So no matter what it take they have to keep up the lie at all cost and make this Horus look like a fraud; even though Horus existed nearly 5000 years before Christ. The Christians are bias, and they would be so disillusion if they were to find out that their faith and Jesus is all a lie. Accordingly the story of Horus existed 2500 to 5000 years BC. So it is not possible that Horus could have stolen the life and story of Jesus Christ.

"Horus was born on December 25th of the virgin Isis-Meri. His birth was accompanied by a star in the east, which in turn, three kings followed to locate and adorn the new-born savior. At the age of 12, he was a prodigal child teacher, and at the age of 30 he was baptized by a figure known as Anup and thus began his ministry. Horus had 12 disciples he traveled about with, performing miracles such as healing the sick and walking on water. Horus was known by many gestural names such as The Truth, The Light, God's Anointed Son, The Good Shepherd, The Lamb of God, and many others. After being betrayed by Typhon, Horus was crucified, buried for 3 days, and thus, resurrected."

The stories are to similar in fact for one not to caste doubt on the story of Jesus Christ. Either Jesus is real or He, The Christian God and the Christian Faith is all a fraud drawn from the story of Horus which can be proven beyond a reasonable doubt.

Comment: This answer shows a complete lack of understanding about ancient history on MANY points.  Assertions such as "no Roman document mentions Jesus" is flat out false...  The "story of Horus" is a quote from the "Zeitgeist" propaganda movie and is completely unbacked by actual Egyptian documents.  No professional historian would even remotely support this position.